# org-reveal - auto split long output from babel block to left side

Tags: org-mode, org-reveal

I have a python code to generate a long output text when export to slide (html). I can manually split the output to two columns for sure. is it possible to do it automatically if output too long?

for example, below code need to update every time data if run python code again (data changed):

```
* frame title
#+header: :eval no
#+begin_src python :results output :exports results
import re
import os
import pandas as pd

def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    idx = 0
    for i in range(0,40):
        df.loc[idx,'x'] = i
        df.loc[idx,'y'] = i*i
        idx+=1
    print(df)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

#+REVEAL_HTML: <table><tr><td>
| x |   y |      |
| 0 | 0.0 |  0.0 |
| 1 | 1.0 |  1.0 |
| 2 | 2.0 |  4.0 |
| 3 | 3.0 |  9.0 |
| 4 | 4.0 | 16.0 |
| 5 | 5.0 | 25.0 |
| 6 | 6.0 | 36.0 |
| 7 | 7.0 | 49.0 |
#+REVEAL_HTML: </td><td>
|  8 |  8.0 |  64.0 |
|  9 |  9.0 |  81.0 |
| 10 | 10.0 | 100.0 |
| 11 | 11.0 | 121.0 |
| 12 | 12.0 | 144.0 |
| 13 | 13.0 | 169.0 |
| 14 | 14.0 | 196.0 |
| 15 | 15.0 | 225.0 |
| 16 | 16.0 | 256.0 |
#+REVEAL_HTML: </td><td>
| 17 | 17.0 | 289.0 |
| 18 | 18.0 | 324.0 |
| 19 | 19.0 | 361.0 |
| 20 | 20.0 | 400.0 |
| 21 | 21.0 | 441.0 |
| 22 | 22.0 | 484.0 |
| 23 | 23.0 | 529.0 |
| 24 | 24.0 |  576.0 |
| 25 | 25.0 |  625.0 |
#+REVEAL_HTML: </td><td>
| 26 | 26.0 |  676.0 |
| 27 | 27.0 |  729.0 |
| 28 | 28.0 |  784.0 |
| 29 | 29.0 |  841.0 |
| 30 | 30.0 |  900.0 |
| 31 | 31.0 |  961.0 |
| 32 | 32.0 | 1024.0 |
| 33 | 33.0 | 1089.0 |
| 34 | 34.0 | 1156.0 |
#+REVEAL_HTML: </td><td>
| 35 | 35.0 | 1225.0 |
| 36 | 36.0 | 1296.0 |
| 37 | 37.0 | 1369.0 |
| 38 | 38.0 | 1444.0 |
| 39 | 39.0 | 1521.0 |
#+REVEAL_HTML: </td></tr></table>

#+OPTIONS: toc:nil num:nil
#+REVEAL_THEME: White
#+REVEAL_INIT_OPTIONS: width:1600,height:800,center:false,slideNumber:true,center:false,transition:'none'
#+begin_export html
<style>
.reveal {
   font-size: 150%;
}
.reveal .slides {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.reveal table td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.reveal table tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
#+end_export
```

[image]

Comment: Split it in two columns where? in the Org mode buffer or in some exported format? I don't think there is any provision to do it in the buffer. As for exported formats, it would depend on the capabilities of the exporter.

Comment: @NickD Oh, yes, I mean when export to slide (html), I wish to show it with two column side by side automatically if it's too long.